# Внутренний if не видит data массив родительской функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

После ajax запроса получаем массив из картинок и выводим 10 из них, теперь нужно настроить так, что бы дополнительно с выведенных картинок я мог снизу добавить любую из них по id ( id указывать в input`е при запросе всех картинок).

JS в двух файлах разных, в коде указанно что где.

Посоветуйте как лучше реализовать.

[image]

```js
// script.js

const resultBlock = document.querySelector('#result')
const pageNumberEl = document.querySelector('#page-number')
const clickMeButton = document.querySelector('#click-me')


clickMeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  getImages(pageNumberEl.value, onDataReceived);
})

function onDataReceived(data) {
  el = data.slice(0, 10)
  el.forEach(el => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = el.thumbnailUrl;
    document.querySelector('#result').appendChild(img);

  })
  prisv(el)

}


// server.js

function getImages(pageNumber, successCallback) {
  $.ajax(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos`, {

    success: function(data) {
      successCallback(data);
    }
  })
}

let idNumber = document.querySelector('#id-number')
// тут ошибка
function prisv(el) {

  if (el.id === idNumber.value) {
    chto();
  }
}

function chto(data) {

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ss
    <-18>
    </-18>
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="click-me">ClickMe</button>
  <input id="page-number" value="1">
  <div id="result"></div>

  <div class="oper">
    <!-- <button id="click-again">ClickAgain</button> -->
    <input id="id-number" value="">

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="server.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: скорее всего надо `prisv(el)` воткнуть внутрь цикла....т.к. ты ожидаешь что el  у тебя будет одним элементом, а на данный момент он у тебя массив

Comment: впинхнул по рекомендации `prisv(el)` внутрь цикла и удалил одно равно со сравнения ибо там разные типы данных ( не знаю как это по другому ( правильно ) можно ещё сделать и всё заработало, за подсказку спасибо!

Comment: `el.id === +idNumber.value` --- так можно к числу преобразовать за счёт плюса перед значением

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а разве не легче будет просто заменить тройной оператор сравнения на двойной? (`==`)

Comment: @ΝNL993 кому как нравится. предпочитаю "явное лучше не явного" чтобы потом не пришлось гадать почему у меня true, хотя данные разные и движок просто преобразовал что-то не явно...... лично я давно перешёл исключительно на ===

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это вам не TypeScript :). К тому же унарный оператор + тоже не луком шитый и похлеще `==` может быть. Но исключительно в этом случае мы знаем какой тип данных передаётся в пропорции, так что `==` не так уж и плох, повторюсь исключительно в этом случае.